# Сохраняется ли изображение при вставке img JavaScript

Tags: javascript

К примеру, у меня есть блок с изображением `<img src=1.jpg>`
Если я удалю этот элемент, а после добавлю снова - изображение подгружается заново или же уже находится в браузере?
Если же подгружается заново - есть ли возможность работать с ним, подгрузив 1 раз?

Comment: "Как только изображение каким-либо образом загрузилось в браузер, оно будет находиться в кеше браузера и будет загружаться намного быстрее при следующем использовании"

Comment: Думаю, это легко проверяется экспериментально